# How to find best number of layer and best size of hidden layer of MLP in GridsearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

I want to use GridsearchCV find best number of layer and best size of hidden layer. I try to set hidden layer as list find best number of hidden layer.

```
   df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\data.csv')
    
    X = df.iloc[:,:20]
    Y = df.iloc[:,20]
    
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
    
    params = {
        'estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': list(range([list(range(10,200,10))]))
  
    }
    
    clf = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=MLPClassifier(),
        param_grid=params,
        cv=5,
        n_jobs=5,
        verbose=1,
    )
    
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(clf.best_params_)
```

I show error like this.

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: why does the interpreter seem to want to interpret your list as an integer? The answer is that you are passing your list as the input argument to range, which expects an integer. Don't do that. Say for i in myList instead.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036309/typeerror-list-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer)